# Master equation of a continuous-time continuous-space linear random walk

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, markov-process, random-walk

A particle continuously moves in $\mathbb{R}^+ = \{x \in \mathbb{R}, x\ge 0\}$. It starts from $0$ at time $0$, and it has a restart probability defined by a pdf on $\mathbb{R}^+$.
If it is at $0$ at time $t$, it samples a restart delay $\delta t$ according to this pdf; it is again at $0$ at time $t+\delta t$ (restart), and it is at $x$ at time $t+x$ for all $x$ in $[0,\delta t)$.

I am looking for **the master equation of the position of this particle over time**, without any assumption on the restart pdf.

I am also interested in a discrete-time, discrete-space random process that converges to the same distribution when the discrete steps go to $0$.

References and suggestions are welcome too!

Comment: Wiener process $W$...

Comment: I agree that this is strongly related to Wiener process, but here we have restarts and, maybe more importantly, no Gaussian increments. Doesn't it make this process significantly different?

Comment: If you have a continuous time random walk, or what is called also a compound renewal process, the CLT does not necessarily applied, so no brownian motion convergence. You also get the fractional master equation that you can look for in the book or papers by Sokolov, or Klafter. Just search the name along side with continuous time random walk.